# Cannot deploy Azure data factory SSIS Integration Runtime using CD release pipeline in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My issue is: I have 3 environments (Dev, Test and Prod) for Azure ADF, I have a DevOps CI pipeline for each environment that generates a ARM template and now I'm building the release pipeline to deploy the ARM template into Test for example. I'm facing now an issue with my SSIS integration runtime that is failing to deploy. I have a dedicated VM for the SSIS-IR in each environment but **same name** across the environments. Now, the properties of each SSIS-IR are different so, I added the following parameters in the ARM template parameter configuration file in the Source ADF instance, so I can get them in the ARM template parameters json file.

- *typeProperties_computeProperties_vNetProperties***vNetID**
- *typeProperties_computeProperties_vNetProperties***subnet**
- *typeProperties_computeProperties_vNetProperties***publicsIPs**
- *typeProperties_computeProperties_vNetProperties***blobContainerURI**

I have override them in the override parameters in my CD pipeline to match the configuration I have in my TEST environement but did not add the "**sasToken**" parameter (it is a secure string).
But when I ran the CD pipeline it failed with error ***[error]IntegrationRuntimeCannotModify: Integration Runtime can only be updated/deleted when it is in 'Initial' or 'Stopped' state***.

It seems like I'm missing something that makes the pipeline believe that it's something different than the ssis-ir already set up in TEST environment and therefore it is trying to modify the existing SSIS-IR.

When I stop the existing SSIS-IR in the target ADF instance (Test), it recreates it successfully with the properties I provided in the override parameters but it failed to start it.

Note: I have an SHIR (Self-Hosted Integration Runtime) that is deploying fine

Need help please!

Comment: Which [deployment mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes) you selected to deploy your ARM template? To help narrow down the cause of the issue, have you tested to use other methods like [Azure deployment templates with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli) to see if the behavior is reproducible?

Comment: I'm using incremental deployment. I didnot try azure CLI. Thanks

Comment: To test with Azure CLI deployment is to help isolate the issue. If the ARM deployment with Azure CLI fails, you may consider sharing a minimal reproducible template contents for further investigation.